# How to properly manage versions of a row in a database?

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, database-design, versioning

I'm developing a web app, I have a Table called " Article " and another called " Section ".
An Article is made of sections. I want to save each article version for each editing made in my web app.

For example, when I edit an article X, i want to increment its version from 1.1 to 2, and keep the content of the old one for Audit purpose.

I've suggested to introduce a New table called "Article_Versions" with a Many to one relationship with the Article Table. So each Article must have many version in the other table, but i was wondering if this wouldn't influence the performances especially that I have to introduce more tables for sections versions and more...

My question is : Is there any "Perfect" practice to solve this kind of problematic ?

Comment: check out Hibernate Envers

Answer (score 0):

There is seldom perfection. Performance is a tradeoff of time and space under usage patterns. Design is a tradeoff of performace vs complexity in use and implementation.

Tables *exists* for recording application relationships like:

```
VAT(V,A,T) -- version V of artcle A has text T
```

When you need to you can split this up:

```
current_VAT(V,A,T) the most recent version of Article A is V and has text T
old_VAT(V,A,T) -- version V of article A has text T AND V is not the most recent version of
-- VAT = currrent_VAT UNION old_VAT
-- is_empty(current_VAT EXCEPT old_VAT)
-- FORALL A,cV,cT,cV,cT [current_VAT(cV,A,cT) AND old_VAT(oV,A,oT) IMPLIES cV > oV]
```

This makes some queries faster and some slower. It is more complicated as a presentation of the base facts. It is also more complicated for some uses but not others.

It's not clear to me what set of tables you are proposing. Yes there is a many-to-one application relationship from articles to versions. But it is expressible as:

```
EXISTS T VAT(V,A,T)
```

So you still need the all-key VAT. (Or equivalent.)